# Python3 Flask Twitter OAuth

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, oauth, flask

I've been trying to use twitter with Flask OAuth and im running Python 3. I've followed this tutorial: http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-OAuth/ and tried some workarrounds but it doesn't work.

This is what I've got so far:

```
from flask import *
from flask_oauthlib.client import OAuth
from User import User

oauth = OAuth()
twitter = oauth.remote_app(
    base_url='https://api.twitter.com/1.1/',
    request_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
    access_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
    authorize_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize',
    consumer_key='My Consumer Code',
    consumer_secret='My Secret Code',
    name='twitter'
)


app = Flask(__name__)
current_user = User()
@app.route('/')
def home_show():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/about')
def about_show():
    return render_template('about.html')

@app.route('/app')
def app_show(): 
    if not current_user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return twitter.authorize(callback=url_for('oauth_authorized',
      next=request.args.get('next') or request.referrer or None))

@twitter.tokengetter
def get_twitter_token(token = None):
    if current_user.is_authenticated():
        return session.get('twitter_token')
    else:
        return None

@app.route('/oauth-authorized', methods=['GET'])
@twitter.authorized_handler
def oauth_authorized(resp):
    next_url = request.args.get('next') or url_for('index')
    if resp is None:
        flash(u'You denied the request to sign in.')
        return redirect(next_url)

    session['twitter_token'] = (
        resp['oauth_token'],
        resp['oauth_token_secret']
    )
    session['twitter_user'] = resp['screen_name']

    flash('You were signed in as %s' % resp['screen_name'])
    return redirect(next_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

It crashes on

```
   return twitter.authorize(callback=url_for('oauth_authorized',next=request.args.get('next') or request.referrer or None))
```

and this is the trace:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
        return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
        response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
        raise value
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
        response = self.full_dispatch_request()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
        raise value
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.dispatch_request()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
        return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
      File "/Users/Karl/Python/tweettosleep/hello.py", line 40, in app_show
        return twitter.authorize(callback=url_for('oauth_authorized',next=request.args.get('next') or request.referrer or None))
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_oauthlib/client.py", line 455, in authorize
        token = self.generate_request_token(callback)[0]
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_oauthlib/client.py", line 527, in generate_request_token
        type='token_generation_failed'
    flask_oauthlib.client.OAuthException: Failed to generate request token
```

Comment: **How** does it not work? Please provide more detail. At the moment it is very difficult to tell what you are asking.

Comment: The idea is to get a token back from the method app_show and that doesnt work. The problem is I cant generate a request token. Let me edit it and add the trace.

Comment: [flask-oauth](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-OAuth/) and [flask-oauthlib](http://flask-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) are different libraries. You mentioned `flask-oauth` but are actually importing from `flask-oauthlib`. You can see the sample code for `flask-oauthlib` [here](http://flask-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/client.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already found the answer, there is actually nothing wrong with the code. Sorry if it's a little bit messed up. The problem was that my consumer_key for twitter isn't valid. I have no idea why. Still figuring out.

So the point is, if you get the same Traceback, there might be a possibility that your twitter consumer_key is not correct!